# How is "Turnover" in HKEX different from "Volume"?

Tags: stocks, terminology, hong-kong

On page 26 of this [PDF](https://www.hkex.com.hk/-/media/HKEX-Market/Products/Listed-Derivatives/Single-Stock/Stock-Options/Statistics/Open-Interest-Distribution/How-to-Read-Open-Interest-Figures/OI_Figures.pdf) provided by HKEX, it describes turnover as:

> each trade concluded in the derivatives market will increase the turnover for that day

Isn't it the definition for volume?

When checking other [documents](https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Statistics/Consolidated-Reports/HKEX-Monthly-Market-Highlights?sc_lang=en) from the HKEX websites, it seems their turnover is in the unit of HK dollar, which is a completely different concept of the turnover ratio in the US market.

Then what is the meaning of "turnover" in HKEX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turnover in Hong Kong is Sum of Price per Share multiplied by Number of Shares of each transaction.